# Why is this SQL return null?

Tags: sql, join, exists

I do not know why this SQL returns no rows:

```
SELECT team_rel.team_id
     , team_rel.login_id 
  FROM team_rel
 INNER JOIN team ON team_rel.login_id = team.login_id
 WHERE team.login_id = '39' 
   AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 0 
           FROM team_rel
          INNER JOIN team ON team_rel.login_id = team.login_id 
                         AND team_rel.login_id = '39' 
                         AND team_rel.team_id  = team.id
       )
```

while the following SQL (the same but without the NOT EXISTS condition) :

```
SELECT team_rel.team_id
     , team_rel.login_id 
  FROM team_rel
 INNER JOIN team ON team_rel.login_id = team.login_id
 WHERE team.login_id = '39'
```

returns:

```
+---------+----------+
| team_id | login_id |
+---------+----------+
|      23 |       39 |
+---------+----------+
|      23 |       39 |
+---------+----------+
|      13 |       39 |
+---------+----------+
|      13 |       39 |
+---------+----------+
|      16 |       39 |
+---------+----------+
|      16 |       39 |
+---------+----------+
|      25 |       39 |
+---------+----------+
|      25 |       39 |
+---------+----------+
```

and the NOT EXISTS subquery (same SQL with test on team_id) returns :

```
SELECT team_rel.team_id
     , team_rel.login_id 
  FROM team_rel
 INNER JOIN team ON team_rel.login_id = team.login_id
                AND team_rel.login_id = '39'
                AND team_rel.team_id = team.id
```

returns:

```
+---------+----------+
| team_id | login_id |
+---------+----------+
|      23 |       39 |
+---------+----------+
|      25 |       39 |
+---------+----------+
```

I would like my first select to return:

```
+---------+----------+
| team_id | login_id |
+---------+----------+
|      13 |       39 |
+---------+----------+
|      16 |       39 |
+---------+----------+
```

but it does not return any rows?!

Comment: Are you missing a where-clause in your sub-select?

Comment: You need to give more informantion if you want us to help you, just posting a SQL statement wont do the job.

Comment: Your sub-query is uncorrelated... It needs conditions referencing the outer query table.

Comment: By "return null" do you mean no rows (not the same thing). As others have noted likely the `not exists` clause is removing all rows but we need sample data to be sure.

Comment: Thanks to all of you.. i added some more information.. please check it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT team_rel.team_id, team_rel.login_id 
FROM team_rel
INNER JOIN team ON team_rel.login_id = team.login_id
WHERE team_rel.login_id = 39
  AND team_rel.team_id NOT IN 
          (SELECT team_id FROM team_rel 
           INNER JOIN team ON team.id = team_rel.team_id AND
                              team.login_id = team_rel.login_id)
```

Comment: thank you.. i did it but it returns: team_id 23 13 13 16 16 25 login_id 39 39 39 39 39 39 while i would like to retun: team_id 13 16 login_id 39 39

Comment: @ShokouhDareshiri You probably need to add samples of your input, that is the content of the two tables, to the question for us to better understand what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: @ShokouhDareshiri, I have updated my answer based on some assumptions I made on what the input is.